# How to link a switch with a service

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a switch that activates a service and with the new Android APIS, when you launch a service, you have to launch a notification, in the notification, add a button in the notification to stop the service, my doubt is how to link the switch for when stop the service by the notification, the switch is also deactivated, because I want the service to be deactivated both in the switch and in the notification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968240/updating-activity-textview-from-service-using-service-binding This served as a solution